# Should we consider info level issues reported by nessus as vulnerabilities

Tags: security, nessus

While running a nessus scan it reported few issues with severity as "info". Should we consider these as security vulnerabilities against that product/module.

Nessus documentation is not very clear on this aspect. Would like to know what is the common industry practices.

Comment: This doesn’t feel on topic here - maybe on http://security.stackexchange.com? (Not knowing the product, just using common sense, I’d guess that „info“ entries do not point to a vulnerability. Either that, or the word „info“ is the wrong choice)

Comment: Is there a way i can move this to security.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Nope, you’d have to delete here and re-ask there (but do check their faq/question guidelines first, I have no experience with what is on topic there and what isn’t)

Comment: You can flag it and ask a mod to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

INFO is not intended to be a vulnerability. It is simply stating a fact. Ex:
`Determined your operating system is <your os name>`
That is not a vulnerability. It may also be telling you of a finding that you need to decide if it is OK. Ex:
`Found port 22 is open`
This is not really a vulnerability either, as SSH (for *nix) runs on port 22. However, if you don't want port 22 open, you need to correct that on your own.
Successes are also reported as INFO. Ex:
`Checking for users with no password. SUCCESS!`

MEDIUM means Nessus ran the test and it was *unable* to determine if the test passed of failed.
An example of this would be that Nessus was unable to scan the sudoers file for NOPASSWD because it isn't readable. This is not a failure. This is not a success. So it will show up as a MEDIUM.

HIGH means that Nessus ran the test and the results indicated a failure. Ex:
`Looking for mounts with nosuid set. Results:`
`Found /tmp/swap`
`Found /share`
`Add nosuid to /etc/fstab`

Hopefully, this helps future users interpret their Nessus results.

Answer (score -1):

In general, these are not vulnerabilities. However these information may come handy, as add-ons to the approach that you might want to take for exploiting the vulnerabilities present in the system.